# jQuery animate display to div if radiobuttongroup isn't answered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, radio-group

I use the following code to see if all my radiobutton groups are checked. If they aren't, then I would like to use jQuery to go to the group that hasn't been answered.

Code to check if the the group is answered:

```
$('.aQuestion').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0)
    {
       alert("checked");
    }
  else
    {
       alert("not checked");
    }    
});
```

And this is how the questions look like. (there is about 90 of them, and they are generated through mySQL.

```
<div class='aQuestion' id='div1'>
    <STRONG>1. </STRONG>
    <STRONG>Question</STRONG></br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='0'>answer 1</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='1'>answer 2</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='2'>answer 3</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='3'>answer 4</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='4'>answer 5
</div>

<div class='aQuestion' id='div2'>
    <STRONG>2. </STRONG>
    <STRONG>Question</STRONG></br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='0'>answer 1</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='1'>answer 2</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='2'>answer 3</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='3'>answer 4</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='4'>answer 5
</div>
```

I'm looking forward to see your suggestions. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? If you want your page to scroll to the div that contains the radioButtons that hasn't been answered yet, this one should work:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

**elementtoScrollToID** should then contain the element of the parent-div that contains the radio buttons that haven't been answered.